# запуск некоторых программ в Fedora 28 приводит к ошибкам

Tags: linux, fedora

две программы в Fedora 28. Одна atom - редактор, вторая skypeforlinux. У обеих при запуске выдается такая вот диагностика atom

```
net.js:10
const cares = process.binding('cares_wrap');
                      ^

Error: EFILE
    at net.js:10:23
    at net.js:1645:3
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:535:7)
    at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:475:18)
    at internal/child_process.js:6:13
    at internal/child_process.js:903:3
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:535:7)
    at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:475:18)
    at child_process.js:12:23
    at child_process.js:542:3
```

в skypeforlinux

```
dns.js:246
    this._handle = new ChannelWrap();
                   ^

Error: EFILE
    at new Resolver (dns.js:246:20)
    at dns.js:377:25
    at dns.js:431:3
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:606:7)
    at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:550:18)
    at net.js:45:13
    at net.js:1730:3
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:606:7)
    at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:550:18)
    at internal/child_process.js:6:13
```

кто знает, как бороться?

Comment: пропробуйте обновить nodejs информация - https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Answer (score 0):

странное решение, но факт, проблема решилась. Atom, skype и vk messenger падали  или не корректно работали (последний) из-за отсутствия доступа к файлу /etc/resolv.conf для обычных пользователей.